# Why does add comment validation '%d more to go...' lie to me?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, character-limit

When I try to cheat the add comment validator by typing something like

```
'Yes.               _'
```

It will not validate. Apparently the real algorithm does not count white space but the JS validator does. Seems like they should be the same. (What is the point of giving people false hope?)

Comment: "When I try to cheat the add comment validator"...maybe don't do that?

Comment: Thats not fair. How do you guys get to do it but not me?!

Comment: @natec Learn markdown ;)

Comment: @nate View the source code of this page to see what they're doing.

Comment: When the student is ready, the master will appear.

Comment: @Ryan: If the JS validator doesn't reflect the server-side one, I'd say that's a bug, not a support issue.

Comment: @pekka who's laughing now, eh? eh? =8-)

Answer (score 5):

We don't like it when people intentionally subvert the comment character limit.

Please leave substantive, useful comments of at least 15 characters, or don't comment at all.

Comment: Did you just kill the empty-link trick too?

Comment: Won't this just lead to "yes -----------" style responses? Was there real harm being done by subverting the limit?

Comment: People will *always* subvert the limit, whether you like it or not. Now they will subvert it in an uglier way, such as the one @Pekka demonstrated =)

Comment: (a.k.a., there are some dirty unicode tricks that still need to be closed off…)