# Recent change in treatment of backticks in comments?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, comments, markdown

Until very recently, typing ```` ``` ```` in a comment gave `` ` ``. Now it gives ```, and I have to type ``` `\`` ``` to get `` ` ``. Can someone explain what exactly was changed recently in comment markdown treatment?

EDIT1: Maybe I'm allowed a second question: Is there any place where I can look up such changes? (It's just not so nice if it happens without any notice.)

**EDIT2:**
Now this is *really* not nice at all: [In my comment here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9762/trouble-with-unicode-math-fontspec-in-xetex/9766#9766) there's a triple backtick instead of a single one in inline code. At this moment, the [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:h_YdU1-skPUJ:tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9762/trouble-with-unicode-math-fontspec-in-xetex+site:tex.stackexchange.com/questions+%22to+mark+your+inline+code+as+I+did+in+my+edit%22&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&source=www.google.com) shows how it looked after I submitted my comment. I posted this comment *a lot of times*, so will they now all look distorted? I added the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a more correct form, requiring explicit escaping.

So I have converted all known instances (under 100) to the correct escaped form.*

````
update PostComments
set Text = dbo.RegexReplace(Text, '(\s|^|\()(```)(\s|$|\)|\.|\?|\,)', '$1`\``$3')
where DeletionDate is null 
and dbo.RegexIsMatch(Text, '(\s|^|\()(```)(\s|$|\)|\.|\?|\,)') = 1
````

(prior to this I removed all instances of ``{4,}` from the system first)

* on SOFU and Tex only; not convinced it's relevant anywhere else

Comment: You are 100% correct with your first sentence. I was just bothered very much about the incorrect rendering of all my old comments. Of those <100, a great percentage came from me. Thanks a lot for fixing this! (I can't say that I understand your code.) Can you please explain what made that change of the old comments in the first place?

Comment: Is the changed effect of the triple backtick connected with [this recent change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74340/backslash-escaping-in-code-regions-in-comments/79218#79218) (which I highly appreciate)?

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour of backticks in comments has always been ... delicate, shall we say.

It breaks on some releases of the software; it gets fixed again later - usually fairly quickly.  It is frustrating; it has happened a lot in the last couple of years (as in a dozen or so times - I've not been keeping a formal count).  There ought to be red warning flags around that bit of the code: "Do not change without running extensive QA on this!".

Comment: Thanks for telling me that I'm not alone.

Comment: I think this was changed intentionally: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79043

Comment: @Jukka: I fail to see the relation. Can you please expand?