# Recent change of inline code in comments leads to mistakes in old comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown

This is a continuation of my question [Recent change in treatment of backticks in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79179/155585), but as that one is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), I think it better to ask a new question.

As explained [here by Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74340/backslash-escaping-in-code-regions-in-comments/79218#79218), backslash escaping within inline code in comments is now disabled *except for the backtick*. While this is great, the problem is that *all the old comments are affected, too*. Over at tex.sx, we got used to having to write `` `\\(` `` in a comment to get `\(`. The result of the recent change is that now there are many instances of `\\(` in old comments where it should be `\(`. (I [had already expressed the opinion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74340/backslash-escaping-in-code-regions-in-comments/77405#77405) that it would be bad to make changes to old comments; I'd prefer if they're left alone.)

Can this be fixed, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I replaced all *seven* of the comment instances where `\\(` or `\\)` occurred on Tex.. not exactly an epidemic, is it?

One example here:

[Is there a test for the different styles inside maths mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/is-there-a-test-for-the-different-styles-inside-maths-mode)

I guess I'll try meta.tex too.

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks a lot! You're right, _seven_ is a lot less than I expected; I see you [found some more on meta.tex](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10/syntax-highlighting/773#773). There you see that the same problem is with `\\[` and `\\]`; can you replace those, too (both on tex and meta.tex)? Another thing: Your replacement of the triple backticks [didn't work for ```.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10043/page-number-position/10044#10044), and it seems that you didn't apply it to meta.tex. In _my_ comments that's about 7 instances; maybe there are more.

Comment: @Jeff: Sorry, one more thing: What has happened to my comment [at that same link on meta.tex](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10/syntax-highlighting/773#773) in which it says "(With the highlighting, I like `$` much better than \` (\` and \` )\`.)" I'm pretty sure I typed `\`\\(\``, and now it looks as if I typed `\\` (\\``. It not so nice that the changes affect old comments; only some are distorted, but I did put some effort into them looking good.

Comment: @hendrik different issue. Spaces *are not allowed* as the start or end character in inline code blocks now. Do not include them, or it won't work. Your comment had spaces as the start or end character in the code block.

Comment: @hendrik I replaced for `\\[` and `\\]` as well. Are we done now?

Comment: Thanks, Jeff, I really appreciate your help here: Even that comment with the funny spaces is fixed; great. So with fixing we're done, I think. Here's a test: a space in the _end_ of inline code is OK, as `\ ` shows. _Please do not change this!_ It's our last workaround to type `\ `. But can you please tell me where I can find the details on how backticks in comments work right now? And when there's another change, wouldn't it be a good idea to leave the old comments unaffected?

Comment: @Jeff: It still seems that all the fixing related to my question above is done, thanks. However, I just saw that [there is another issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79546/155585), namely that the enforcement of backslash escaping of backticks has [more negative effects](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8076/can-one-define-a-superexpandaftern-that-would-expand-to-2n-1-expandafter/8117#8117) (my comment of `Jan 4 at 17:19`, currently the 4th from below). My main point is to underline the last question in my previous comment.

Comment: @Jeff, sorry for keeping nagging: [Here I observed some quirky behaviour in inline code in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79546/155585). If you have `<br>` then you can also have `<br>`s without a space. Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: @Jeff: Whereas, if you have `<br />` then you can't have `<br>`s. Weird! I'd really like to know what exactly is possible and what is not.