# Comments are not allowing me to add code anymore

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

So even yesterday (14/09/12), I could add comments with code embedded between them using the ` key. But now, it doesn't seem to work anymore. Is this an intentional removal?

Comment: Any `examples`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you referring to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444990/updating-remote-database-table-from-local-database-table#comment16733898_12444990)?

> Try this for your error handler: ` or die (mysql_error());`, then tell us the result.

Yeah. For some reason, they aren't parsed into `<code>` tags when there are spaces around them within comments, but do so just fine in answers. I escaped them above for illustration; here's the same comment in the answer field without the escape characters:

> Try this for your error handler: `or die (mysql_error());`, then tell us the result.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or by design though. Maybe one of the devs can shed some light on this.

Comment: thanks a lot Daniel! Also, how did you know it was that one?

Comment: @think123: I just skimmed through your comment activity and that particular one caught my eye.

Comment: I guess this is by design. If you want to use backticks inside Markdown code, then you start with a group of backticks and a space, and close with the same thing backwards. I guess that's why the space still is special in mini Markdown too, though in comments one needs to escape the backtick to show it in code.

Comment: I only play a dev on TV, but yeah, [this is `bydesign`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79254/recent-change-of-inline-code-in-comments-leads-to-mistakes-in-old-comments/79344#comment193706_79344) (and the same holds true for the `[]()` link syntax)

Comment: @Tim Stone: Is this applicable only to comments and not posts? That entire question revolves around Markdown in comments, but Jeff didn't mention if it was applicable to posts as well...

Comment: Yeah, posts are unaffected.