# Single code formatted space ` ` works in questions and answers but not comments

Tags: bug, comments, code-formatting

It's annoying that on stack overflow ` ` works fine in questions and answers but not in comments, to produce a single code-formatted space.

**Edit a few days later**

Actually my question appears to be a duplicate of [Markdown in comments: Inline code section does not format correctly if it contains only white-space](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105557/markdown-in-comments-inline-code-section-does-not-format-correctly-if-it-contai?rq=1) which is marked as a duplicate of [My comment `code block` was not converted properly, is this a bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105316/my-comment-code-block-was-not-converted-properly-is-this-a-bug) which in turn cites a comment by Jeff which **is apparently no longer visible** in the thread at [Recent change of inline code in comments leads to mistakes in old comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79254/recent-change-of-inline-code-in-comments-leads-to-mistakes-in-old-comments/79344#79344)

The duplicate-spotting code didn't locate these initially but some of the people who edited my question and/or posted relevant answers managed to include enough material to make the duplicate-spotter suggest it in the right sidebar.

So now it's all as clear as mud to me.

Comment: Test: It's annoying that ` ` works fine in questions and answers but not in commas.

Comment: meta seems to behave differently - meta doesn't do code formatting?

Comment: Yes it does. It should be the same as on SO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836321/simple-regex-i-cant-seem-to-catch-the-period/15836462#comment22532786_15836462 direct link (I hope) to the comment with the single spaces which don't work, the answer above has working ones.

Comment: It works for me.  Can someone please explain how to repro?

Comment: IMO you should explicitly type out "space" to make your sentence easier to read, either in the answer or the comment.

Comment: Test leading space `​ lead`, test trailing space `trail `. Space `​ `.

Comment: Perhaps. But code-formatted single characters are quite a natural way to discuss analysis of strings character by character and programming languages with special symbols. Anyone the point of my question is the difference between comment and Q&A, not the feature's existence at all.

Answer (score 4):

It is certainly annoying not being able to properly `codify` leading space, trailing space, repeating space, and space as the only character within backticks in comment.

It is possible to force `codification` when the text within backticks starts with spaces **in comment**, by putting an invisible leading character Zero-Width Space U+200B before the leading space. (No Break Space U+00A0 does not work here).

**In post**, the `codification` happens when there is leading space, but no leading space is preserved. To workaround, you only need to use No Break Space U+00A0 as the leading space.

It is possible to force retention of repeating spaces and trailing spaces (in both post and comment), by using No Break Space U+00A0.

Comment: As demo, `​ leading space`, only space `​         `, `repeating        spaces with trailing spaces         `.

Comment: Thanks. Useful (but fiddly) workaround. Of course I understand that comments are intended to only support a subset of the markdown supported by the posts, but this particular difference just seems odd to me.