# Mismatch between comment caption and applied comment rules

Tags: bug, comments, spam-detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does add comment validation '%d more to go…' lie to me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79043/why-does-add-comment-validation-d-more-to-go-lie-to-me)

If you type a comment there is a caption which informs you of how many characters you need or have left if you exceeded that threshold. However this caption does not seem to reflect the rules that are applied, e.g. if i have *"1 more to go.."* and i just add a space at the end the caption will now say *"585 characters left"* but if you try to submit the comment it will not let you do so.

I presume that tailing whitespace "doesn't count" but the caption only reflects the raw character count.

[image: screenshot]

Apologies if this has been pointed out before, it's a minor issue and i could not find anything on it.

Comment: Your presumption is correct. The validation algorithm upon submission is "pickier" than the raw character count displayed as you type. Attempting to subvert the comment limit is strongly discouraged. You shouldn't leave a comment at all, unless you have some useful information to contribute. And that will always take more than 15 characters.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I disagree, if a question is talking about some implementation/code the person wrote in which there is a problem and that code is not in the question then just asking for the code  may take as little as 5 characters and that comment will be far from pointless.

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: Nope, that took more than 15 characters. No problem found. "Code?" is not good enough. Use full sentences.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I was writing a full sentence, it had 14 characters, why the <insert swear word here> has the system to be such a nazi...

Comment: Because if it wasn't, people would abuse it and post comments like "lol" or "hi" or "thx" or "haha" or "yes" or "ok"... And we don't want that. The risk is that a handful of respectable users are occasionally frustrated and have to add extra words. There have been *rare* occasions that I've wanted to answer a question with simply "Yes", but I can't do that. I still think the compromise is well worth it to keep down "noise" in the comment threads.

Comment: Well put, @Cody. That limitation does have its downsides, but the advantages outweigh them by far.